# Set meshes for each frame of the animation?

Tags: animation, alembic

When you export a cloth simulation as an alembic file and then import it again, you get a modifier on the cloth mesh called "Mesh sequence cache". The meshes in the sequence are read from file. What I want to know is whether it is possible to set custom meshes into keyframes to get a custom animation with a single mesh?

Comment: Have you looked into the *Mesh Cache* modifier?

Comment: Yes and it requires a pre-existing file .abc to work. It exists solely for that purpose. I want to set my own meshes to each frame in the editor.